# Deploying AWS XRay Daemon with Nestjs application in single Docker Image

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, amazon-ecs, aws-xray

I have a Nestjs application for which I create a docker image and pushes it to AWS ECR. From there, it is being used by the AWS Batch Job. The Batch Job create services and task in ECS, pulls the image from ECR and run it.

This is the original content of DockerFile.

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN rm -rf node_modules

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build:prod

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

This is the docker build command that i uses

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t <someName> .
```

NOTE: I'm using M1 Mac, thats why i have to add platform option for build.
Till now, everything is working fine.

Now, I wanted to add the AWS XRay in this application. I have added the aws sdk, downloaded the xray daemon on my local machine, ran it, and it worked without any issue. I cna see the traces on AWS Console.

Now to use it on ECS, I have updated my dockerfile to this:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN apk add unzip
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl -o daemon.zip https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/aws-xray-assets.us-east-2/xray-daemon/aws-xray-daemon-linux-3.x.zip
RUN unzip daemon.zip && cp xray /usr/bin/xray
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/xray", "-t", "localhost:2000", "-b", "localhost:2000"]
EXPOSE 2000/udp
EXPOSE 2000/tcp

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN rm -rf node_modules

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build:prod

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

After deploying the image, when i execute the batch job, All i see is the daemon has started running but my nestjs application has not started. I only see the log of xray daemon.

So I changed the way to start the daemon as background process.
I replace the following code

```
RUN unzip daemon.zip && cp xray /usr/bin/xray
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/xray", "-t", "localhost:2000", "-b", "localhost:2000"]
EXPOSE 2000/udp
EXPOSE 2000/tcp
```

with

```
RUN unzip daemon.zip 
RUN ./xray -o -n <Regoin> &
```

But now nothing is running. I getting error:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh exec format error
```

This error should happen when I'm build from a different platform for a different platform. Thats why I ws passing --platform option during build.
Any idea why it is not working or any different way to achieve it ?

Comment: A Docker container only runs a single process, and the usual best practice is to run two processes in two separate containers.  In the Docker documentation, [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) discusses some ways to work around this as well.